# Page refresh should not cause page to scroll up, using jquery

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I have written a piece of code, which every 30seconds cause, page to reload.

```js
refreshRequest = setInterval(function() {
  document.location.reload(true)
}, 30000);
```

But my concern is when I go down the page and after 30 seconds when the page refreshes, then again my page scroll's to the top.
I see in the code that when the page refreshes then the below code gets executed.

```js
var diaryScroll = $(".diaryBody").scrollTop();
$(".diaryBody")[0].scrollTop = diaryScroll;
```

which takes the page to the top.
Can I know which element or component if I use in place of `.scrollTop`, will retain the position of the page?

Thanks,
Shresh

Comment: When your page is reloaded, all variables are reset, so `diaryScroll` cannot keep the value. You can maybe try with [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead, or you could pass the scroll position in the URL to the reload

Comment: Hi sir,Thanks for your time :) , I tried removing true inside reload, still that didnit work. how can i pass the scroll position in the URL?

Comment: Yeah I removed my comment after having read the Docs, the parameter is force to get the page from server, to prevent the browser to load from cache, so it may not be the good solution for what you want

Comment: Reloading the page every 30 seconds seems... bad.  What's the goal for that?  Are you trying to get new data from the server every 30 seconds?  Instead of reloading the *entire page*, just use AJAX to fetch only the updated data and write that updated data to the page.  It's much less traffic over the network, a better user experience, and has the added bonus of not having the problem you're currently trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to store scroll location in localStorage:

```
$(function () {
    if (!localStorage.scroll_position) {
        localStorage.scroll_position = 0;
    }
    // on load scroll to last stored scroll location
    $(document).scrollTop(localStorage.scroll_position);
});


$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    // store last scroll location
    localStorage.scroll_position = scroll;
});
```

.

BTW I wonder why you use page reload to show the latest update where you can use ajax to load the page smoothly.